# Converting KML to GeoRSS

Tags: google-maps, kml, georss

Does anybody know how I can convert a KML datafeed into GeoRSS data?  I have a legacy map application and it looks like Google only outputs in KML.  I need to get this data as GeoRSS.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:  The app I'm working actually runs on a Bing map - it was just using Google's GeoRSS output in order to allow the client to edit their own markers.  Google stopped allow GeoRSS data feeds and now I can only get KML output.

Comment: http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/03/kml-and-georss-support-added-to-google.html

Answer (score 0):

I did find a service that can do this from Bing.  Here is the URL, followed by a URL encoded link to your KML feed:

http://www.bing.com/maps/GeoCommunity.asjx?action=retrieverss&mkt=en&mapurl=